# Can able to built chromebook/chrome os Desktop application using node webkit?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-os, nw.js, chromebook

I have created Desktop application using node webkit for Windows and Mac is it possible to create for chromebook/chrome os.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome os we can built extensions.